# Problem with installing windows 7 back to my pc

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have problem with installing windows 7 back to my pc. I have make windows 7 boot on my USB but when i choose USB in boot menu my pc just skip that and start ubuntu again and when i restart my pc i don't get option to enter boot menu. Help?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Windows 7 default is BIOS and if you want an UEFI install you have to make some modifications to make it UEFI boot. Otherwise it indicates you did not correctly make a bootable flash drive. And if a new computer with UEFI Secure boot you must have Secure boot off.

Comment: If i understand you i need to make windows bootable for UEFI if i want to work? I don't have secure boot my pc is older.

Comment: Can you tell us your motherboard model (run in terminal: 'sudo dmidecode | less')?

Comment: If system is older and not UEFI, then you only can install in BIOS boot mode to MBR partitioned drive. NTFS partition must be primary and have boot flag for Windows to install to it. But you must have a valid Windows bootable BIOS flash drive.

Comment: How to know is my system UEFI?

Comment: My PC is UEFI i now check.How to create bootable USB from ubuntu because i obviously make mistake?

Comment: Convert Windows 7 install to UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Since you have failed to provide the model, I can only give you loose guidelines.

A) Use the correct <kbd>f1</kbd> key to enter the BIOS during startup and change the boot order,

**OR**

B) Use the correct <kbd>f1</kbd> key to open the boot menu and select the Win 7 USB drive.

Also, make sure that you have Legacy boot enabled if this is a UEFI computer.

Comment: I try that and don't work